# How to make a script which runs on login?

Tags: login-items

My ISP requires me to login to their server and keep the login page up so I can use the Internet, which makes me uncomfortable while I download some big files. After some research i found a script which is supposed to run on Linux environment, which you can find [here](https://github.com/anoopjohn/Asianet-Auto-Login-Script).
Can I make this script run on my Mac while I log-in?
Also the script provides some keep-alive functions, can I make them work in my Mac?

Can I add these features with script?

### Features

1. Automatically connect to Asianet Dataline without having to sign in via the
   browser.
2. In startup and free mode the script will keep the connection alive.
3. The script will automatically reconnect if connection breaks because of a
   power failure or a line problem.

I am using a Macbook 5,2 running Lion 10.7
Please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the script on its own? Open Terminal.app, make sure it's executable by running `chmod +x /path/to/script`, then run it with `/path/to/script`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that script *should* run on OS X. It is a .sh file and it's using the bash shell, so I'd assume that it would run, unless it requires programs that aren't installed on OS X by default.
**To have it run on login:**
Just go to System Preferences > Users & Groups and click on the user that you want the script to load. Click the <kbd>+</kbd> button to add a login item and navigate to your script. The script will load automatically on login.

Comment: Hi, Please see my edit. I have more doubt.

Comment: The "features" that you requested are part of the .sh script itself. Looking at the README file on github, those are the *exact* features the script provides. Have you tried running it on OS X yet?

Comment: Try to run it from Terminal.app first. If this works as you expect, login automation is the next step.

Comment: @NikhilMohan To run it, open Terminal and drag and drop the file onto the Terminal window, then hit enter to make it run. Note: You do need to edit the .sh file to include your username and password.

Comment: @daviesgeek i did drop the script in terminal. But nothing happens.

Comment: Did you hit Enter/Return?

Comment: yes i id see screenshot http://s13.postimage.org/9n3f54ivr/Screen_Shot_2012_09_17_at_9_38_55_PM.png

Comment: `chmod +x` isn't the command to run the script, it just prepares makes the script executable. To run it, type `/Users/niksmac/Personal/auto-login.sh` followed by enter.

Comment: @daviesgeek yeah you are a genius. i got it working, but a small warning. `date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`

Comment: The OS X `date` doesn't support `-d` as needed by the script.